# margin-top: auto to send last list item to bottom, but item is getting cut off

Tags: html, css

I have a 100% height sidebar that contains a div and a ul. The div is going to be used for an image at the top of the sidebar and the ul is going to be used for all of the sidebar menu items. Adding the div item to the ul is not an option here it needs to be separate.

The last item of the ul must be at the bottom of the sidebar at all times.
I am attempting to use margin-top: auto to achieve this. It works perfectly when the ul is the only item in the sidebar, but due to the div being above the ul the last item in the list gets pushed off of the screen.

How can I prevent this? Below is my HTML and CSS. The goal is to get the flag icon to always appear at the bottom of the sidebar, still having both a div and ul in the sidebar.

**I do not want to use absolute positioning as a solution because when the screensize is small the bottom item will overlap the others.**

```css
body {
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: #F7F7F7;
    }

    .container {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      flex: 0;
      background-color: #464F57;
    }

    .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .header {
      flex: 0;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-bottom: solid 2px #eaeaea;
    }

    .content {
      overflow-y: auto;
      flex: 1;
    }

    .menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 20px 0 0 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .menu li:last-child {
      margin-top: auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-flag fa-3x"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer maximus aliquam accumsan. Aenean vel dui tellus.
          Nulla porttitor ante augue, et posuere ex consequat ac. Nulla eget vestibulum leo. Aliquam </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bottom: 0` and `position: absolute` to solve your problem. In that case your sidebar should have `position: relative`. Check out this link of [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) to know in details about this style.

Here's the working code([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzm67j0d/6/)):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0;
  background-color: #464F57;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header {
  flex: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eaeaea;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-flag fa-3x"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer maximus aliquam accumsan. Aenean vel dui tellus. Nulla porttitor ante augue, et posuere ex consequat ac. Nulla eget vestibulum leo. Aliquam </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is correct but I think that this is a bad design choice as if the view height is lower than the sidebar height, the components will overlap and make the sidebar unusable. The sidebar should have a minimum height of its content and the container should allow vertical scrolling in my opinion.

Comment: @SystemGlitch what way are you suggesting I keep this same layout and enhance it? I do not want to use absolute positioning here. When the screen-size is really small the bottom item will overlap the others. I want it to always stay below.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention in my post that I do not want to use absolute positioning here because when the screen size is really small the bottom item will overlap the others. Is there a way to do it using flexbox and margin-top: auto and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
body {
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: #F7F7F7;
    }

    .container {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      flex: 0;
      background-color: #464F57;
      position:relative;
    }

    .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .header {
      flex: 0;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-bottom: solid 2px #eaeaea;
    }

    .content {
      overflow-y: auto;
      flex: 1;
    }

    .menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 20px 0 0 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .menu li:last-child {
      position:absolute; bottom:0;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the flag in the bottom of the side bar 
Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention in my post that I do not want to use absolute positioning here because when the screen size is really small the bottom item will overlap the others. Is there a way to do it using flexbox and margin-top: auto and make it work?

Comment: Try this .menu li:last-child {
      margin-top: 56.4vh !important;
  }